# Node JS, how can I use Squlize.create corectly

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying from like 1 day ago to solve this. Why my async function is not awaiting for the results ? The data is inserted correctly in the database, but graphql doesn't get the results before they query is finished.

```
const resolvers = {
    register: async (
        parent,
        { contact_name, username, password },
        { models }
    ) => {
        const user = {
            contact_name,
            username,
            password
        };
        const registeredUser = await models.Member.create(user)

        try {
            if (typeof registeredUser.member_key === 'number') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
    Member: {
        config: (parent, args, { models }) => {
            return models.Config.findAll({
                where: {
                    member_key: parent.member_key
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I `console.log` just after `const registeredUser = await models.Member.create(user)` I get the following returned:

```
member {
    dataValues:
       { member_key: null,
         contact_name: 'Alex',
         username: 'tornado',
         password:
          '$2b$12$6MKWx.LUXXXaIHHIFUp1DuOMkMNLc76HcvTN6ZayLv.a7iG70O3JK' },
      _previousDataValues:
       { contact_name: 'Alex',
         username: 'tornado',
         password:
          '$2b$12$6MKWx.LUXXXaIHHIFUp1DuOMkMNLc76HcvTN6ZayLv.a7iG70O3JK',
         member_key: null,
         member_type: undefined,
         email_address: undefined },
      _changed:
       { contact_name: false,
         username: false,
         password: false,
         member_key: false,
         member_type: false,
         email_address: false },
      _modelOptions:
       { timestamps: false,
         validate: {},
         freezeTableName: true,
         underscored: false,
         paranoid: false,
         rejectOnEmpty: false,
         whereCollection: null,
         schema: null,
         schemaDelimiter: '',
         defaultScope: {},
         scopes: {},
         indexes: [],
         name: { plural: 'members', singular: 'member' },
         omitNull: false,
         sequelize:
          Sequelize {
            options: [Object],
            config: [Object],
            dialect: [MysqlDialect],
            queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
            models: [Object],
            modelManager: [ModelManager],
            connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
            importCache: [Object],
            test: [Object] },
         hooks: { beforeCreate: [Array] } },
      _options:
       { isNewRecord: true,
         _schema: null,
         _schemaDelimiter: '',
         attributes: undefined,
         include: undefined,
         raw: undefined,
         silent: undefined },
      isNewRecord: false,
      null: 34490 }
```

and in the last line of code the member_key is specified but not updated in dataValues, I'm doing something wrong for sure but I have no idea what. 
BTW member_key is the usual ID, only custom to reflect my old database :)

And the problem with this is that the graphql query gives me an error too because it's finishing before I can get the results back from the db, I assume because await is not working on this line:

const registeredUser = await models.Member.create(user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this one, by returning the token. Because I need the token anyway in the front end so I added the member_key, username, and contact_name to token creation so I have them in the token.

Here is the fix for the register mutation some else is still getting a similar problem

```
register: async (
    parent,
    { contact_name, username, password },
    { models, secret }
) => {
    const user = {
        contact_name,
        username,
        password
    };
    await models.Member.create(user);
    const member = await models.Member.findOne({
        where: { username }
    });

    if (!member) {
        throw new Error('There is a problem with the registration');
    }
    return {
        token: createToken(member, secret, '30m')
    };
},
```

also add the missing fields to token creation for me they are member_key and contact name, here is the modified sign token

```
const createToken = (user, secret, expiresIn) => {
    const { member_key, contact_name, username } = user;
    return jwt.sign({ member_key, contact_name, username }, secret, {
        expiresIn
    });
};
```